# Wix- Unable to write to XML file when using Property Name as Value

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I am trying to write a value into an XML file during the installation, this value comes from a text field which user fills it during the installation stage.
In my GUI file for the installer I have the following EditField:

```
 <Control Id="LogEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="155" Width="100" Height="18"  Property="LOGVALUE" Text="{80}" />
```

In my Product.WXS I have added a new property like below :

```
   <Property Id="LOGVALUE" Secure="yes"/>
   <SetProperty Id="LOGVALUE" Value="" After="AppSearch">LogValue</SetProperty>
```

And then I have created a new component like below:

```
<Component Id="LogComponent"
    Guid="87F682A6-1CC0-4E2D-9882-25D765478F94" Directory='ContentDir' NeverOverwrite='yes' Permanent='yes'>
  <File Id="Logconfig"
        DiskId="1"
        Name="log.xml"
        Source="..\bin\log.xml"
        Vital="yes"
        KeyPath="yes" />

  <util:XmlFile Id="SetKey3"
                Action="setValue"
                ElementPath="/log/appender[\[]@type='log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender'[\]]/file/@value"
                Value="[LOGVALUE]"
                File="[#Logconfig]"
                SelectionLanguage="XPath"
                Sequence="1" />

</Component>
```

I have also added reference of this component into the .
The problem is after installation nothing will be written into the XML file, **However** if I replace **Value="[LOGVALUE]"** with some hardcoded values like **Value="TEST"** in the util:XmlFile section it works. Any ideas where the mistake comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of LOGVALUE to "" within the below setproperty I believe that is breaking it by setting the value to nothing, set it to "[LOGVALUE]" or don't set it at all as the UI is setting the property value

```
<SetProperty Id="LOGVALUE" Value="" After="AppSearch">LogValue</SetProperty>
```

Comment: It works with thanks :) Amazingly I am writing to another XML file within the same Product.WXS and I am setting the value to "" for <SetProperty> field and it works as expected but for this one it doesn't work unless I set the Value = "[LOGVALUE]".